# How does the Random() deals with those milliseconds when in reality they are out of range to the function?

Tags: java, random

Okay, I understand that the `Random()` in Java gets its seed from the system date and time by default in milliseconds.

Having said that, if I'm not mistaking, a seed in milliseconds it looks like the following: `967884300000`. That is `09/23/2000 9:45:00`.

I keep getting out of range when I do `Random dice = New Random(967884300000);`

I understand it is out of range but that's an actual seed at some point when using the system time.

Is there something I am missing? how does the `Random()` deals with those milliseconds when in reality they are out of range to the function?

Comment: It does not need the complete time since the epoch. The last bit will do. That is due to the day, month, year, hour is quite predictable

Comment: This is answered in the Javadoc -- the constructor acts as if calling setSeed, and setSeed specifies a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Random(seed)` constructor accepts a `long` number, not `int` one, but when you write `new Random(967884300000)`, you are trying to create an `int` literal, which is out of range. In Java to create the `long` literal, add an `L` suffix to the end:

```
Random r = new Random(967884300000L);
```

Note that official documentation of `Random()` default contructor does not explicitly state how exactly it's created, thus the implementation may vary. For example, [OpenJDK 8](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Random.java#Random.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) implements some sofisticated algorithm using the `System.nanoTime()` and additional `AtomicLong` to ensure that consequent calls have different seed values (on some systems `System.nanoTime()` resolution is quite low, so consequent calls may return the same value).

Comment: and about that nanotime(). i saw that function in the Random class source code. The RNG uses milliseconds righ? and not nanoseconds

Comment: @henry, why do you think so? milliseconds are not used at all. nanoseconds are used and they are only used to initialize RNG when default constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `Random` whatsoever. You could change the code to a variable initialization and you would get the same error. It is simply a missing `L` at the end of your numeric literal.